# Rate button (link to my app on App Store) not doing anything

Tags: app-store, xcode7, nsurlconnection

Here's the creation of my button:

```
- (void)rateInfo {
    UIButton *rate = [UIButton rateCreate];
    [rate addTarget:self action:@selector(rateButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEvenTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:rate];
    rate.frame = _mainLayout.rate;
}
```

Here's the `rateButton:` method:

```
#define YOUR_APP_STORE_ID XXXXXXXXXX
// and yes, I have my actual number in the code
/*
 *
 *
 *
/

static NSString *const iOS7AppStoreURLFormat = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%d";
static NSString *const iOSAppStoreURLFormat = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%d";

-(IBAction)rateButton:(id)sender {
    [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0f)? iOS7AppStoreURLFormat: iOSAppStoreURLFormat, YOUR_APP_STORE_ID]];
}
```

Is that how I'm supposed to write this out?  When you tap the rate button, it generates the URL?  If so, I don't know why it's not working.

Two things:

```
 1.  My app just went live on the store (it's a puzzle game called Twinstones if you want to try it out).
 2.  I'm signed into Apple when I'm trying to connect
```

Answer (score 0):

`rateButton:` method is just creating the URL. You should tell the application to open the URL. You can do it like;

`NSURL *appStoreURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: iOS7AppStoreURLFormat, YOUR_APP_STORE_ID]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appStoreURL]];`

removed the iOS version check because old URL isn't working anymore.